# Run javascript/jquery inside a script template (script in a script tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, tags

I have a client side CMS div that gets loaded into script template.  I need to run a script inside that div.   How can I run myFunction inside this script tag?  It's closing the first script tag early :(

```
 <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-foo">

 <div id="myCMSdiv">

 <p> My Content </p>

 <script>
 myFunction();
 </script>

 </div>

 </script>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: This is invalid HTML, you can neither render the <div> nor the <script> tag that way in another <script> tag. Can you explain in more detail why you are forced to this structure and what you actually wanna do?

Comment: How did you place that JavaScript snippet in the html script in the first place?

Comment: updated.  I have to add my content client side via a CMS.  My content gets added to the page in the #myCMSdiv.   I can put anything I want inside that div via the CMS but I can't control how it is placed on the page.  (via the script template)

Comment: I believe that there is something wrong in your CMS - it should not place the <div> inside the <script>. Which CMS is it?

Answer (score 0):

Give a bit of context of how your CMS binds the template (the JS file)
If your CMS uses `template` binding then you can just use `afterRender`.

Just like this:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  this.myFunction = function() {
    console.log("test");
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'tmpl-foo', afterRender: myFunction }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-foo">

  <div id="myCMSdiv">
    <p>My Content</p>
  </div>

</script>
```

More info on `template` binding [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).

If your CMS uses it as a `component` though then you need another approach.
Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243756/does-afterrender-work-with-knockout-components) on how to do it but the gist is just the same as above.